# Force resources and services cache for offline development

Tags: caching, web-applications, development-environment, developer-tools, offline-caching

i am a web developer and recently i frequently found myself developing with reduced connectivity.
Everything works fine except the integration part with external services.
I was wondering if anyone knows about a tool that can create a sort of a snapshot of all my requests and then serve them also without connectivity. A sort of heavy-duty forced cache. It would be okay also to intercept every http request of the entire virtual machine, the only thing that i need is to be able to reset or exclude some resources, the ones i'm working on.

Does anyone know something like this?